# Parsing JSON object containing an array with Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

Ok, I'm having some difficult with this.

My JSON is like

```
{ "names" : [ {"name":"bla"} , {"name":"bla2"} ] }
```

I was trying to do [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/Video/hh237494) but, due to the different JSON, it didn't worked.

What do I have to put inside this method?
I don't know if it's better to create a "wrap" class that contain my list or using directly a JsonObject. Could you provide me a snippet? I'm kinda new in C#.

```
void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;
        try
        {
           ???
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ will be your friend. It creates classes and members according to a JSON String. It saves a lot time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (which supports Windows Phone)

```
string json = @"{ ""names"" : [ {""name"":""bla""} , {""name"":""bla2""} ] }";

var dict = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var obj in dict["names"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj["name"]);
}
```

Or if you want to use it in a type-safe way

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(json);
foreach (var obj in dict.names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.name);
}


public class RootClass
{
    public MyName[] names { get; set; }
}

public class MyName
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Mike_G OP doesn't use `DataContractJsonSerializer` either. I see only `DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;` Is this the only explanation of your downvote for a **working** code ?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks a lot! If anybody need a string (like me) just put obj["name"].ToString(). Maybe it's something noob but, as I said, I'm new in C#!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using JSON.NET ( http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx ) normally, so my code might vary a bit.

For the list content I would go for a class with a name property like that:

```
public class NameClass {
    public string name { get;set; }
}
```

Then you should be able to deserialize with JSON.NET a `List<NameClass>`:

```
List<NameClass> result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<NameClass>>(jsonString);
```

This is written out of my head, so maybe, it doesn't compile with copy and paste, but it should work as a sample.

Comment: -1 Doesn't work since OP's json string is not an array or a List. Easy to test

Comment: Have overseen the need for a root class. @L.B: Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

Using the .NET DataContractJsonSerializer you will need to define a class that maps the json objects.  Something like this (if i remember correctly):

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name
    { get; set; }
}

 /// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class Results
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "names")]
    public List<Result> Names
    { get; set; }
}
```

then in your event handler:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Results));
var results = (Results)serializer.ReadObject(SOME OBJECT HOLDING JSON, USUALLY A STREAM);
```

Comment: -1 Doesn't work since OP's json string is not an array or a List. Easy to test.

Comment: of course it doesnt work, its not a program lol.  he wasnt wanting it done for him, he asked what to do next.  As you can see, i demonstrated to two major components for completely his task.  Lol, some people....

Comment: Your answer was trying to deserialize OP's json string to a **List not to a root object** and you say now `of course it doesnt work`. Good policy to answer. Just write anything random, since you don't expect it to run. LOL