# C#: Correct Encoding of escaped Unicode-Characters in a local string (i.e.: not \\u20ac)

Tags: c#, .net, string, text, encoding

**C#**: I have a string that comes from a webpage's sourcecode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var itemsLocalDeals = [{"category":"HEALTHCARE SERVICES",
"dealPermaLink":"/deals/aachen/NLP-Deutschlandde
5510969","dealPrice":"399,00 \u20ac",..........
```

I do some things with that string, such as extracting the **dealPrice** and add it to a List<> (in the whole string are more than one *dealPrice*).

Is there a method to decode all "*\u20ac*" to their real character ("€")?
There are also other characters, so not only the €-Character has to be decoded.

**When I debug my code and look at the local fields/variables the string contains not the "€"-Character but the escaped sequence "\\u20ac".**

Something like myString.DecodeUnicodeToRealCharacters.

I'm writing the result to a (UTF-8)result.txt

Thanks alot!

P.S.: Unfortunately .Net 2.0 only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Unescape("\u20ac");`

But better use a json parser since your string seems to be a json string(starting with `[{"category":"HEALTHCARE SERVICES",.....`)

Comment: Thanks, Regex.Unescape is just fine for me. EDIT: I'm using HTML Agility Pack. --> JSON-Parser?

Comment: After getting your string using HtmlAgilityPack you can use a Json parser Like [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) or [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). For ex, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403037/parsing-json-object-containing-an-array-with-windows-phone-7/10403167#10403167

Answer (score 1):

```
public string DecodeUnicodeToRealCharacters(string s)
{
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the code you're using to write the text?
this one works just fine:

```
string str = "\u20ac";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\trythis.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8)){
    sw.Write(str);
}
```